# Accessing document within coffeescript's default wrapper

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Coffeescript wraps your code into a wrapper like

```
(function() { 
/* your code */
}).call(this);
```

Here, `this` means `window`. So, to create a public interface I do something like

```
this.publicObject =
  someMethod: ->
    document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML = "Changed!"
```

I can then register a callback in the HTML document invoking my .js file with something like `<span onclick="publicObject.someMethod();">Click</span>`.

However, what if I wanted to call someMethod from the .coffee file (<strike>to be called on document ready, I think</strike> EDIT: See accepted answer + comments below)? If I just follow the above code up with

```
publicObject.someMethod()
```

it seems like the document object is not accessible within someMethod due to context issues. **How can I call `publicObject.someMethod()` from my .coffee file and have it recognize `document`?**

Note: `apply()` and `call()` trickery is OK, but I don't want to get rid of the wrapper, if possible. If you care, I use the following to compile my script:

```
coffee -j -p -c coffee/*.coffee > www/app.js
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wrapper doesn't hide `document`, which is a global because it's attached to `window`. Unless you've declared a variable named `document` within your `.coffee` file (by writing `document = ...`), `document` will be accessible from `someMethod`. Try adding `console.log document` to the top of `someMethod` to check for yourself.

So there must be something else going on. What exactly is the error message you get when `someMethod` is called?

Comment: When I call `publicObject.someMethod()` from my .coffee file, the exact error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`. So I thought, "Perhaps coffeescript doesn't compile onload?" In fact, this is true. When I call `window.onload = publicObject.someMethod` my code runs as expected (no errors and "button1"'s HTML is updated to "Changed!"). P.S. If you want to edit your answer for others to see more clearly the issue, that'd be great.

Comment: Sounds like you assumed that the `.call(this)` wrapper would be equivalent to `document.onload = ...` or the ubiquitous `$(...)` powered by jQuery. It just runs the function immediately, though, whether `button1` exists or not. An alternative solution would be to move the `<script>` tag to the end of `<body>`; see http://encosia.com/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/

Answer (score 4):

Just do `window.publicObject.someMethod()`.  This avoids the whole variable `this` scope issue.  You can use `this` and `window` interchangeably in the top level scope of you CS code, but once you get inside functions, you'll need to use `window`.  I suggest using `window` all the time as its A) clearer and B) sidesteps the whole `this` issue which has caused countless hours of head scratching.

Also, this is the namespace pattern I use.  I create 1 top-level global object and hang everything off of that neatly.  It starts like this.

```
OT = window.OT = {} #root of the public API namespace
OT.someNestedPublicObj = {}
```

Comment: For those seeing this in the future: `window.publicObject.someMethod()` does the same, in my case, as `publicObject.someMethod()`, but I agree with Peter that I should start using `window` instead of `this` (it's clearer, simpler).

Comment: I handle this a bit differently. I use `root = window ? global` to grab a root namespace. Then when exporting, I do something like `root.exportableMethod = exportableMethod`. In consumers I do `exportableMethod = root.exportableMethod` to import the name from some other file.