# Coffeescript wrapping files in a function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

The coffeescript compiler is, for some reason, wrapping all of my .coffee files in a function when they are compiled. For example, if I have test.coffee:

```
class TestClass
    constructor: (@value) ->

    printValue: () ->
        alert(@value)

printAValue = () -> 
    test = new TestClass()
    test.printValue()
```

then I get test.js:

```
(function() {
  var TestClass, printAValue;
  TestClass = (function() {
    function TestClass(value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
    TestClass.prototype.printValue = function() {
      return alert(this.value);
    };
    return TestClass;
  })();
  printAValue = function() {
    var test;
    test = new TestClass();
    return test.printValue();
  };
}).call(this);
```

My simple html file won't work with this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="printAValue()">
    </body>
</html>
```

I haven't worked with much JS before, and I wouldn't doubt the coffee compiler, but is the way it should work? How

Comment: Try changing your coffeescript line to pass a value to the TestClass initializer -`test = new TestClass('hello world')`

Comment: See [my answer here][1] on sharing code between JS files/modules.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951438/accessing-document-within-coffeescripts-default-wrapper/6951641#6951641

Comment: This is by far the most popular question asked about CoffeeScript on SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6481986/66226, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4214731/66226, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5693211/66226...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never add event listeners in HTML. Add them in your JavaScript, preferably in the same scope in which you define the event handler.

```
printAValue = () -> 
    test = new TestClass()
    test.printValue()

document.body.addEventListener('load', printAValue, false)
```

If you absolutely need to export something to the global scope, export to the window object:

```
window.printAValue = () -> 
    test = new TestClass()
    test.printValue()
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for solving that problem. But now I'm getting an issue where if I include multiple js files in my HTML, they aren't getting access to each others classes. Is that because they're all being defined in the some non-global scope, and that's where I'm looking for them?

Comment: Yes, they are all wrapped into a function. Create some global namespase object (`window.NS = {}`) and export your classes into that namespace (`NS.TestClasses = TestClasses`).  The namespace will be accessible globally across files.

Comment: You can also replace `printAValue: ->` with `this.printAValue: ->` which is the same thing as `window.printAValue: ->` if you look at the thiss carefully. :-)

Answer (score 9):

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951438/accessing-document-within-coffeescripts-default-wrapper/6951641#6951641) on sharing jS code between files/modules.  Also FYI the wrapper function is by design to prevent unintentional global variables. You can disable with by passing `--bare` to the coffee compiler command line tool, but it is a best practice with good reason.