# PhoneGap CoffeeScript Hello World

Tags: cordova, coffeescript

I´m new to PhoneGap/CoffeeScript trying to get a Hello World App running in iOS and wonder what I´m doing wrong.

This would be my standard index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">


  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.6.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="app.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body onload="onBodyLoad()">
  <h1>Hey, it's Cordova!</h1>
  <p>Don't know how to get started? Check out our <em><a target="_blank" href="http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS">Getting Started Guide</a></em>

  </body>
</html>
```

And the app.js generated from app.coffee looks like this:

```
(function() {
    var onBodyLoad, onDeviceReady;

    onBodyLoad = function() {
        return document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    };

    onDeviceReady = function() {
        return navigator.notification.alert("This alert never happens!");
    };

}).call(this);
```

When I delete the first line "*(function() {*" and the last line "*}).call(this);*" of the app.js get the alert and everything is working properly. 
But I guess there´s a better way than deleting this lines everytime CoffeeScript compiles into JavaScript.

thank you very much,
Jakob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coffeescript wraps each file in a function to prevent it from polluting the global namespace. If you *really* want to do it this way, you could change the declaration of `onBodyLoad` to `window.onBodyLoad`, but best practices explicitly oppose placing Javascript calls in HTML elements like `onload`.

This is a variation on a [popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082373/coffeescript-wrapping-files-in-a-function#comment8477696_7082373). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7082464/760389) is an example of how you can use an event listener to unobtrusively have your function called when the page has loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help, I thought window would be something else in PhoneGap/Webview.

Answer (score 1):

CoffeeScript offers a `bare` option `-b` which disables the wrapping.