# Laravel Elixir creating wrong JS from coffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, gulp, laravel-elixir

First I will provide some examples:

1. [First](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%23%20CoffeeScript%0A((%24)%20-%3E%0A%23%20your%20code%20here!%0A)%20jQuery)
2. [Second](http://js2.coffee/#coffee/try:((%24)%20-%3E%0A%20%20alert%20%27Hello%27%0A%20%20return%0A)%20jQuery)

Both examples of some online compilers create the same result from the same input.

If I take the input, put it into my coffee file and compile it using laravel-elixir, I get this:

```
(function() {
  (function($) {})(jQuery);
}).call(this);
```

Can someone please tell me why?

It's not that I am unable to work with (Some major testings worked very well), but I want to understand the outcome and what I did wrong.

HINT:
I know I am using Elixir on top of Gulp. I didn't check what will happen with i compile my coffee with another Gulp Addon instead of Elixir. The thing is: I will use Elixir and want to know what's different.

If possible, I want to get elixir to produce the expected output like in 1. and 2.

Comment: Straight from the fine manual: ["Although suppressed within this documentation for clarity, all CoffeeScript output is wrapped in an anonymous function:  `(function(){ ... })();` This safety wrapper, combined with the automatic generation of the `var` keyword, make it exceedingly difficult to pollute the global namespace by accident."](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coffeescript wrapping files in a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082373/coffeescript-wrapping-files-in-a-function)

Comment: @fracz There is a similarity, but it is not the same topic... He wonders why it is wrapped, I wonder how I get 2 results from 3 compilers. I expected the output to be like the links I provided... But local the compilers something else instead. Maybe you got some docs about how I can wrap it up so I can get something like `function() { this('#id'); }.call(jQuery);` Thank you in advance...